# Rails System Test: how to set default_host_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

- Rails: 5.2.1
- Out of the box test setup
- Running with chrome as driver (both normal and headless)

I am trying to run a System test where I access a external service, then get redirected back to my own application.

In this system test, how do I get access to the full url of the running test? I cannot find the current localhost port, therefore cannot send the correct redirect url to the external service.

Answer (score 5):

After some more searching the internets, I found an answer.

Based on this [post](https://www.benpickles.com/articles/71-dynamically-setting-default_url_options-in-capybara), I added

```
def setup
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = Capybara.current_session.server.host
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:port] = Capybara.current_session.server.port
end
```

to my `application_system_test_case.rb`.

This allows all `_url` methods to work in the system tests.

Comment: I would put that in the shared test helper, not in just one test file. Otherwise, you'll be repeating it in every single system test.

Comment: @TomLord I put it in the `application_system_test_case.rb`, so it is set for every system test.

Answer (score 3):

Rails 6. The only thing that worked for me:

```
# inside a subclass of ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest or ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
setup do
  self.default_url_options = {...}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for Rails 6.1.6:

The default host seems to have been `127.0.0.1`. To get it to match the server host and port in my development environment, in `application_system_test_case.rb` I used the following:

```rb
class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  def setup 
    Capybara.server_host = "localhost" # or whatever you use in dev
    Capybara.server_port = 3000 # ditto
  end

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 7.1.0, none of the answers above would work, but this did:

```rb
module ActionDispatch
  class IntegrationTest

    def setup
      host! 'localhost:3000'
    end
  end
end
```